# Angular how to generate dynamically component without the selector tag

Tags: html, angular, svg

I am struggling to generate components dynamically without their component tag. Basically I have a main component with a svg picture in it.

I'm trying to write a component witch is going to generate rectangles inside that tag svg. I tried following the angular tutorial for dynamic components, but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUX57.png) is what I get when I generate the component:

Unfortunately, due to the ng-component, nothing is displayed.

here is the component template :

```
@Component({
  selector: '',
  template: ``<svg:rect width="1000px" height="1000px" fill="white">``,
  styleUrls: ['./shape-tool.component.scss']
})
```

here is my main component html :

```
<div class="main">
    <svg #svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="400" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <ng-template svgDynamic></ng-template>
    </svg>
</div>
```

I only want the rectangle tag to get in the svg tag when the user clicks the main component.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove the selector, this can be fixed using CSS only, just set `shape-tool` as `display: contents`,

```css
    shape-tool {
        display: contents;
    }
```

As stated on `display: contents` [documentation](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents), this causes to appear as if the component were direct children of the element's parent. That way there's no need to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Dynamic Component Loader** 
Using Dynamic Component loader, you can change your template during runtime

**Userful Links**

[Angular-dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

[create components in Angular dynamically.](https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d?gi=1e7ca1d4d60b)